# cannot uninstall awscli on mac high sierra

Tags: pip, homebrew, aws-cli

I have recently upgraded to Python 3 with `brew`. My awscli has stopped working because it is trying to use the old version of Python. I would like to try to reinstall it, but currently I am not able to uninstall it.

```
➜  ~ python --version
Python 3.6.4
➜  ~ aws confgure
zsh: /usr/local/bin/aws: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: no such file or directory
➜  ~ pip uninstall awscli
Cannot uninstall requirement awscli, not installed
➜  ~ pip3 uninstall awscli
Cannot uninstall requirement awscli, not installed
➜  ~ brew uninstall awscli
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/awscli
➜  ~ aws configure
zsh: /usr/local/bin/aws: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: no such file or directory
➜  ~ which aws
/usr/local/bin/aws
```

What else can I try to uninstall awscli?

Comment: removed `/usr/local/bin/aws`. not sure if it was the best way

Comment: Running `brew doctor` will show you if there are any leftovers from packages not properly uninstalled.

Comment: didn't `brew upgrade awscli` work? I usually don't uninstall, but maybe I'm not understanding the sequence of events.

Comment: I was never able to uninstall it. It was always saying `bad interpreter` instead of `aws not found`. I fixed it with `brew install awscli && brew link --overwrite awscli`. But the question was how to remove it completely. Cause I wanted to install it with pip.

Comment: Homebrew itself suggests to remove it with `rm`:

`Could not symlink bin/aws
Target /usr/local/bin/aws
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/aws'`

Answer (score 11):

As homebrew say when trying to uninstall/install awscli:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/aws
brew link awscli
```

Almost, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `pip` is now set to your `python3` `pip` (`pip3`). Try using `pip2`.
Also reinstall is a function supported by brew and pip.
This command fixed my friend's installation:
`sudo pip2 install --force-install awscli`

Disclaimer: It fixed it after he tried a bunch of other things so I don't know if only this command is enough to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

user988346's solution worked for me, however, it required using argument `--force` rather than `--force-install` as that's not a valid argument.

`sudo pip2 install --force awscli`

(Sorry for not putting this as a comment, I've not yet met the reputation requirements for this.)